# Old sci-fi story about Alien planet with psychic ocean

Tags: story-identification

Back in the day I had to read a story from the "recommended" books section and I chose this.

The story is about a guy (let's call him Steve) having to visit a planet that already has a human base set up, but I think they lost contact with the inhabitants, which prompted the reason for Steve to be sent off there. He had some kind of experience that was useful for the mission.
As I remember, Steve wasn't that keen on the idea because the planet was pretty far, so it would take years to reach it.

When Steve reached the planet, it turned out that most of the inhabitants were gone sans for one guy he finds later at the base.

The planet had a vast ocean that, the longer Steve was on this planet, the more he felt like it could talk to it. Something along the lines of the ocean being a sentient being.

After being on the planet for a while, Steve suddenly finds his girlfriend there, which should be impossible. Pretty sure he found her naked, and by close inspection it turned out that she had smooth soles "smooth as a child's that has never walked before", implying it's a clone planted by the sentient ocean for X reason. He later develops feelings for this girl (since she looks like his girlfriend/wife). I also think that the original girl is dead, or they broke up, some tragic background story. The girl was worried that Steve likes her because she looks like his previous partner, but Steve assures her that while they look the same, she acts different.

Steve got a cell sample from the girl, and upon closer inspection under the microscope it turned out that the cells are made up of something smaller than an atom, so small that their equipment couldn't focus enough to actually see the thing the cell is made of.

I never finished the story, so I don't know what happens in the end, but that's all the info I remember.

Comment: I like the movie Tarkovsky made out of the book too. Pt 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-4KydP92ss  Pt 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXa6XpaxBS0

Comment: It is one of my favorite books. I like a lot the way that it is kind of a philosophical Scifi dealing not only with the possibility of finding intelligent extraterrestrial life, but how this intelligence can be different from ours and the implications of it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe this is probably [*Solaris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(novel)) ([1961](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1330320), English translation [1970](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1176)) by Stanislaw Lem.

Kris Kelvin is sent from Earth to Solaris, where there is a research stations studying the gel-like organism that inhabits the world-spanning ocean.  He meets Snow, now in charge, and finds Gibarian, the former head, has killed himself.  The only other live human on the station is Sartorius.

Nevertheless, he meets Rheya, a former lover of his who killed herself on Earth, and observes the appearance of other seeming people who could not actually be there.  (These are simulcra constructed by the sentient organism in the ocean for unknown reasons.)

The bit about the soles of her feet is fairly distinctive; first when he finds Gibarian's visitor:

> I looked again at the soles of her naked feet; they had not been flattened or deformed in any way by the weight which they had had to carry.  Walking had not calloused the skin, which was as unblemished as that of her shoulders.

And again when he meets the simulcrum of Rheya:

> Leaning forward, I took hold of one of her ankles and ran my fingers over the sole of her foot.
>
> The skin was soft, like that of a newborn child.
>
> I knew then that it was not Rheya, and I was almost certain that she herself did not know it.

The cells of the simulcra are composed of neutrinos, so smaller than can be resolved.

> "The atom is the ultimate constituent element of our bodies.  My guess is that the Phi-beings are constituted of units smaller than ordinary atoms, much smaller."
>
> "Mesons," put in Sartorius.  He did not sound in the least surprised.
>
> "No, not mesons...  I would have seen them.  The power of this instrument here is between a 10th to a 20th of an angstrom, isn't it?  But nothing is visible, nothing whatsoever.  So it can't be mesons.  More likely neutrinos."

Comment: Thank you so much! This is definitely it. I'm still amazed how people can find old books from other people obscure memories.

Comment: @tinyatom You're welcome!  Sometimes it's not all that hard because the memorable bits are often memorable for other people too.  Plus it's a lot of fun figuring them out.

Comment: You've got to love the "science" in science fiction. The charge radius of some mesons, like the pion and the kaon, is on the scale of 10^(-15) meters. One tenth of an angstrom is about 10^(-11) meters. Even if mesonic molecules were stable, expecting to see them with an instrument of that sort would be like expecting to see a cell with the naked eye. As for the stability or even the possibility of a molecule made entirely out of neutrinos, let alone one that was indistinguishable from normal matter....

Comment: Neutrinos interact incredibly weakly with baryonic molecules. They don't partake of the strong force, so I expect that it would take an extremely high-magnitude gravitational field to make them "solid" (if that's even possible). The likelihood that they would be capable of replicating baryonic matter in that state is essentially nil, I think.

Comment: @Adamant We'd probably go for axions nowadays.

Comment: Indeed. Just to clarify something: mesons are even a bit larger than protons or neutrons, so mesonic atoms might not be very small. But the analogy drawn is seemingly that meson:Phi-creatures as atom:human, such that they are made of mesons, not mesonic atoms. Of course that is in itself an error, since the book should be saying that they are made of mesons rather than protons or neutrons. Really the whole argument is a bit of a mess.

Comment: @Adamant Maybe I should recommend that you never watch *Star Trek*? :-D  I've long since learned to mentally render any non-plot-important scienceological stuff as "blah, blah, blah"; it makes me much less grumpy. :)  FWIW, I was just rereading *The Skylark of Space* and that approach allowed me to instead be cranky about the characterizations and general racist/sexist tone. :)

Comment: I don't like to choose. ;) If it's bigoted, boring, and bad science, that just means you can criticize all three. :)

Comment: While I was sure from the beginning of the description that this was _Solaris_, there's another set of books about a sentient biosphere that I also enjoyed as a kid, _The Jesus Incident_, _The Lazarus Effect_, and _The Ascension Factor_ written jointly by _Dune_ author Frank Herbert and poet Bill Ransom. They are closely connected, and theoretically sequels to Herbert's _Destination Void_, but they stand entirely independent of that, and are written in a very different style. I enjoyed them, and (at least the thirteen year-old me) would very much recommend them. I might give them another try.

Comment: @Adamant : it's handled in the novel, it's even beautifully lampshaded (the author wasn't ignorant in the topic of physics) I remember that the characters are very surprised as they know neutrinos should not behave like this, they shouldn't interact with matter and shouldn't be stable enough to build physical forms. But as Solaris can manipulate spacetime seemingly at will (this is how they discovered it at the beginning, a planet in such a ternary star system shouldn't have a stable orbit yet it did!), so it must be some kind of "field" Solaris is maintaining, to hold the simulacra together.

Comment: The author clearly knew some physics buzzwords, granted. But unfortunately, saying that there must be some "field" being maintained that makes neutrinos behave like organic molecules is basically gibberish, even if the author did say that. It's like saying that there's radiation that makes pizza indistinguishable from motorcars, except slightly more silly. It is fantasy without the self-awareness.

Comment: I am looking at a translation, so perhaps the author really does know what they're talking about and it's the choice of words in the translation that obscure it. But it does not seem that way. Another example: Two theories are contrasted for what happens when the the neutrinos are destroyed. Either the energy is emitted as light, or as gamma radiation. Well, the only problem is that gamma radiation is *a kind of light*, though I suppose perhaps visible light was intended.

Comment: More obviously, it's implied that a burst of (visible?) light with the energy of an atomic bomb would be "powerful, but not destructive". This is untrue: in fact, part of the risk from an actual atomic bomb comes from high-intensity (partly visible) light that can cause serious burns, fires, etc. Then, it's also stated that an explosion of 5^7*10^8 ergs (approximately 7.81^10^6 joules) is equivalent to a small atomic bomb. This is kind of funny: it's on the order of magnitude of the kinetic energy of object with a mass of 1560 kg traveling at 100 km/hour. A small car driving on the highway.

Comment: (Obviously, I checked the Polish edition just to make sure that this really was ergs, and that a helpful translator had not translated it from joules to ergs without changing the number. It was ergs). Also, it is probably worth pointing out that the idea of a "field" that "easily" destroys large, massive conglomerations of neutrinos, without a large input of energy is quite fictional.  There is a way to do that in real life: antineutrinos, one for each neutrino. Producing such a large mass of antineutrinos is not inexpensive, and would not be harmless to "ordinary matter" in their way.